# Problem with initial values (Differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So i'm trying to solve a trivial problem but sadly I'm not good with math and i need help.

SO I solve this equation $y'+y=2$ the solution was $2$, and the initial value $y(0)=2$.

How can I check that ? I don't understand it.

$\frac{1}{e^x}\int(2e^x) = 2$ (Is this solution correct?)

Comment: Plug $2$ into the ODE.  $(2)'=0$ and thus, $(2)'+(2)=2$ satisfies the ODE along with the given condition $y(0)=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check if your answer is a solution to an ODE (or PDE for that case) by simply taking the appropriate derivatives and plugging them into the initial ODE. In your case

$$ y(x) = 2 \implies y'(x) = 0 $$

Therefore, your ODE becomes

$$ y' + y = 2 \implies 0 + 2 = 2 $$

which is true for all $x$. Thus the solution you found is correct.

Comment: i did a mistake and the initial value was $y(0) = 0$ anyway i guess it's the same process and same result $0+0=0$ i hate maths